# not able to Execute testng.xml using Gradle+Intellij

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gradle, intellij-idea, testng

I am building  a framework where  want to run multiple test using testng.xml file. On building the testng.xml file, I am seeing compilation error . Below is my testng.xml file[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="All Test Suite">
    <test verbose="2" preserve-order="true" name="LoginTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="src.test.java.LoginTest"></class>

        </classes>

    </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: Please try to set class name="LoginTest"

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify `<class name="LoginTest"></class>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).